# Is it possible to create formatted email on the iphone 4s?

Tags: iphone, email

I'd like my email from my phone to look like the email from my MS Outlook. The email from my phone looks like ASCII, and there is no way to create a signature with a logo as far as I know. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

iOS 5 brought some limited rich-text formatting options to Mail. When you're composing an email, select the text you want to format, and tap the right arrow. You'll see a button labelled "BIU", tap that and you get options to bold, italicize or underline the text. You can also control the indentation level.

[image: iOS Mail Formatting]
(Image from [Macworld](http://www.macworld.com/article/163008/2011/10/up_close_with_ios_5_mails_changes.html))

As you can see, it's fairly limited, and to my knowledge there's no way to insert a signature with any images. You could keep the logo you want in your iPhone's Pictures and copy/paste it as necessary, but that's obviously very labour intensive.

Your could look into alternative mail apps. There aren't a lot to choose from, but something like [MarkdownMail](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/markdownmail-send-html-email/id390094543?mt=8) might work well for you. It's just meant for composing HTML formatted emails, you'd still use the built-in Mail app for checking, etc.

Comment: Thanks I found this useful for adding Bold to a signature on mail